# Add Video to Login Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a video to display on my login screen. Here's my code:

```
import AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h
import MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h
import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

@interface AuthenticationViewController (){
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

@end

@implementation AnimatedLoginViewController

@synthesize player;

- (void)ViewDidLoad
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    NSURL *movieUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"demo"      withExtension:@"mp4"];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    player.view.frame = screen;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [self.player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playVideo)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification
                                           object:player];

[player play];
}

-(void)playVideo{
[player play];
}
```

All I get right now is a black screen and the video that is called demo.mp4 isn't showing when I access the view controller when running the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: where is [player play]; ?

Comment: @pawan Sorry forgot to add the rest of my code. This still doesn't work. I've updated the original question.

Comment: Where is this code being executed? in `-(void)loadView` or `-(void)viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as this was voted to close while OP was updating the question in response to comments.

Comment: @taz this is in the ViewDidLoad. I'll update that.

Comment: @HectorLopez, I've just tried your code and it's working for me. Are you sure the `movieUrl` is not nil and the file is actually in the bundle? I would suggest having a look to see if the file is in the bundle and add checks to see if the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your code and it's working as expected for me.

Usually if the URL provided is nil or the file doesn't exist, the movie player is not able to locate it, hence the black screen.

I would first check to see that the file is being added to the bundle. You can do this from the project settings. The next steps would be to add code to ensure the file exists.

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:movieUrl.path]) {
    NSLog(@"File doesn't exist at path: %@", movieUrl.path);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Load Error!" message:@"File doesn't exist" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```